# Where this function attains its maximum?

Tags: special-functions

I have been trying to prove that the function
\begin{equation} 
(2-x)^{2k-p}\int_0^1t^{\frac{k}{p}-1}(1-tx)^{-\frac{k}{p}}dt, \,\,\, x\in [0,1]
\end{equation}
attains its maximum at $x=1$ under the hypothesis that $k \geq 2, \,\,\, k+\sqrt{k(k-1)} \leq p \leq k+\sqrt{k(k-\frac{1}{2})}$.

Some plotting seems to suggest that the function is convex which would solve the problem, but I was not able to prove convexity analytically.

Comment: The second derivative of the function is positive in $[0,1]$; hence, your function is convex.